# FLASH AS3 change bitmap on click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, papervision3d

I'm hoping one of the many helpful FLASH genius' on this site can share the code bit necessary to update the bitmap in this sample code: http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_096_3d_cylinder_box 
When clicked I want to have any of the picture's (bitmap) changed to something else (another bitmap) upon the click event.
Thank you greatly for any assistance you can provide!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Nothing intelligent. I'm pretty much a noob at AS... I can cobble bits of code together and make them work, but fresh code is too much of a learning curve for the few times I need FLASH.

Comment: Don't expect working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ExampleBitmapData:BitmapData = ExampleBD();
var anotherBitmapData:BitmapData = anotherBD();

var bitmap_Holder:Bitmap;

bitmap_Holder.bitmapData = ExampleBD();

stage.addChild(bitmap_Holder);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void{
bitmap_Holder.bitmapData = anotherBD();
});
```

this can give you an idea i think.